# Allow SSH login but limit the user to access whole system

Tags: ssh

I want to allow SSH access for user to use services like SCP, GIT or SSH tunneling.  However, I don't want them to use the console shell function from bash.

I force to turn on loginShell as /bin/bash for SSH access or else they can't login to SSH.  If I use /bin/false as loginShell, they can't login to SSH at all.  However, /bin/bash access allow them to use ssh program putty to login to the system.  How may I restrict it?

Comment: please search this site for similar questions, there are many.

Comment: Can you suggest few questions related to it?

Comment: This is the best answer I found. This is a bit heavy handed since it disables si for many users but it gets you closer. https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/271853/how-to-restrict-su-from-root-to-nis-clients

From there,

Answer (score 0):

Just make a group for users that aren't admins or sudoers but can ssh. Lots of info about this if you look into Users and Groups in any Linux manual.